# Search filter with method get doesn't found results [symfony2]

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a search form  that works with the method `POST`, but the method `POST` doesn't display the requested data in the url.

With method `POST` the url look like this:

```
/search_flight
```

with the method `GET` no results found, the url look like this:

```
/search_flight?from=Cape+Town%2C+International+CPT&to=Johannesburg%2C+O.R.+Tambo+International+JNB&departuredate=2016%2F01%2F08&arrivaldate=2016%2F10%2F04&price=57.5%2C1000
```

I also noticed that with the method `GET` the data is reset in each input of the form.

**routing.yml**

```
searchFlight:
    path: /search_flight
    defaults:  {  _controller: FLYBookingsBundle:Post:searchtabflightResult }
    requirements:
        _method: GET|POST
```

**controller**

This method send the requested data to the method `searchtabflightResultAction` that will handle the query.

```
public function searchtabflightAction()
{
    //$form = $this->createForm(new SearchflightType(),null, array('action' => $this->generateUrl('searchFlight'),'method' => 'GET',));
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed(null, new SearchflightType());
    return $this->render('FLYBookingsBundle:Post:searchtabflight.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

.

```
<form action="{{ path ('searchFlight') }}" method="GET">
{# here I have my forms #}
</form>
```

.

```
public function searchtabflightResultAction(Request $request)
{
    //$form = $this->createForm(new SearchflightType());
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed(null, new SearchflightType());
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $airport1 = $form["to"]->getData();
    $airport = $form["from"]->getData();
    $departureDateObj = $form["departuredate"]->getData();
    $arrivalDateObj = $form["arrivaldate"]->getData();
    $price = $form["price"]->getData();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->searchflight($airport1,$airport,$departureDateObj,$arrivalDateObj,$price);


    return $this->render('FLYBookingsBundle:Post:searchtabflightResult.html.twig', array(
        'entities' => $entities,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

How can I make my search filter works with method get ?

Comment: From you question isn't clear what do you want to achieve. Do you want ideally one route which is gonna take GET variables and show them in the form or searchTabFlichtAction to process GET variables and provide them to searchTabFlightResultAction via POST and show them in the form?

Comment: @HonzaRydrych In the index page I have a form where users can select in a dropdown from which city they leaving from and which city they going to, they can can also set the date of departure and arrival. Once the user submit the data he will be forward to the results page. In the results page the user have another form where he can change the data that he have inserted in the home page, he also have one more input where can specify the price. What I would like is the data that have been inserted in the form in index page should be display in the url of the results page.

Comment: The only way I found to display the data in the url of the results page , was to submit the form with the method GET, but with the method GET no results is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything should be done within two actions, the basic concept is:

SearchFlightType has with/wo price option:

```
class SearchFlightType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('from', FormType\TextType::class)
            ->add('to', FormType\TextType::class)
            ->add('departuredate', FormType\TextType::class)
            ->add('arrivaldate', FormType\TextType::class);
        if ($options['price']) {
            $builder->add( 'price', FormType\TextType::class );
        }
        $builder
            ->add('submit', FormType\SubmitType::class);
    } 

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'price' => false,
        ));
    }
}
```

Controller.php

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/index", name="index")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $defaultData = array();
        $form = $this->createForm(SearchFlightType::class, $defaultData, array(
            // action is set to the specific route, so the form will
            // redirect it's submission there
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('search_flight_result'),
            // method is set to desired GET, so the data will be send
            //via URL params
            'method' => 'GET',
        ));

        return $this->render('Post/searchtabflight.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/search_flight_result", name="search_flight_result")
     */
    public function searchTabFlightResultAction(Request $request)
    {
        $defaultData = array();
        $entities = null;
        $form = $this->createForm(SearchFlightType::class, $defaultData, array(
            // again GET method for data via URL params
            'method' => 'GET',
            // option for price form field present
            'price' => true,
        ));

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // get data from form
            $data = $form->getData();

            // process the data and get result
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entities = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->searchflight($data['from'], $data['to'], ...);
        }

        return $this->render('Post/searchtabflight.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            // present the result
            'entities' => $entites,
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: It works nicely! Thanks for the help, I owe you one. :)  I had to change this line:`$form = $this->createForm(SearchFlightType::class, $defaultData, array(
            'method' => 'GET',
            'price' => true,
        ));`   by this one   `$form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed(null,SearchflightType::class, $defaultData, array(
            'method' => 'GET',
        ));` , because I had this in the url `fly_bookingsbundle_searchtabflight`.

Comment: I'm checking in the API and Symfony's 2.7/2.8 there's already `Controller::createForm()` method, so it should work (assuming you're not on no longer supported 2.3). Anyways, there's no need to use `FormFactory::createNamed()` method if you don't name the form, there's `FormFactory::create()` which suits your needs.